# Drivers for the Tenda twl541u wireless card?

Tags: 10.10, wireless, drivers, usb

I have a Tenda TWL541U wireless usb card and I cannot make it work with Ubuntu 10.10 64 bits. I've tried the Windows XP drivers with ndiswrapper to no avail. In Windows 7 I've made it work with using the Vista 64 driver. Does anyone can help? I'm quite a noob in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I did make it work. It was quite hard to find the driver. I did a lsub command in terminal to find witch manufacturer made my card and it turns out was Marvell. After that I found that was a 88W8338 card. Googled it and found a driver named D00000055_87, downloaded it, and after that (since my ubuntu is a 64 bit one) used the driver 64 bit in the file, with ndiswrapper. Then, violá!, wifi with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

May be [this](http://www.alstevens.co.uk/how-to-install-wireless-usb-drivers-for-ubuntu/) will work.

Comment: it doesn't. As I said before, even with ndiswrapper and ndisgtk, It didn't work. I've tried with the vista drivers and with the xp ones, with no result. My version of ubuntu is 10.10 64bit